# What is the most useful String helper that you've encountered?

Tags: c#, string, helper

What useful helpers for String manipulation to you have to share?

I once wrote a replacement for String.Format(), which I find much more neat to use:

```
public static class StringHelpers
{
    public static string Args(this string str, object arg0)
    {
        return String.Format(str, arg0);
    }

    public static string Args(this string str, object arg0, object arg1)
    {
        return String.Format(str, arg0, arg1);
    }

    public static string Args(this string str, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        return String.Format(str, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public static string Args(this string str, params object[] args)
    {
        return String.Format(str, args);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
// instead of String.Format("Hello {0}", name) use:
"Hello {0}".Args(name)
```

What other useful helpers do you have for strings in C#?

Comment: I'm not using any. Yours looks cool.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to include a CultureInfo object with String.Format. You could include a default CultureInfo in your extension method.

Comment: A related example you might find interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322037/how-can-i-create-a-more-user-friendly-string-format-syntax/1322103#1322103

Answer (score 4):

A fairly popular one that is more of a convenience extension method is the following:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string s)
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }
}
```

Nothing great, but writing `myString.IsNullOrEmpty()` is more *convenient* than `String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)`.

Comment: I use to do this, but then in retrospect decided to remove it because you could be calling a method on a null.

Comment: While it's true that this one is popular (and I do use it often... probably mostly out of laziness), I am not really a fan of it. There are some good arguments against it in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790810/is-extending-string-class-with-isnullorempty-confusing